# How to create new model and serialise json into it

Tags: c#

Relatively new to C#, filling in for someone. There are a couple posts similar to this but I didn't quite understand them and didn't give clarity on the problem I'm having. I'm using Asp.net Core, C#, Razor pages.

I have a Json file, called "ResponseExample.json". I have a model called "ResponseModel" that is pretty much a replica of the data formatting / data set.

What I am trying to achieve is to put the JSON file data into my new model. Then I am assigning the model to session, so I can display the data on the view page. This is what I have so far so you can see what I am trying to achieve.

My problem currently is that I am not creating the model right so I cannot assign the json data to it. I'm not entirely sure the JSON deserialize is correct either.

```
public string LoadJson()
 {
     using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("ResponseExample.json"))
     {
          string json = r.ReadToEnd();
          return json;
     }
}

public void SetSessionRatingResponseData(JObject response)
{
     new ResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(LoadJson());
     Set(SessionConstants.Response, ResonseModel);

}
```

Comment: Please add an example of the JSON string and the model class to help us better assist you here.

Comment: Is this the actual code? The first method looks correct, but the second one has a host of problems, most of which should be giving you compilation errors.

Comment: Aside from the syntax errors, your code seems to be a bit "scatterbrained". Your `SetSessionRatingResponseData` method gets the json data from a file by calling the _LoadJson()_ method. Yet, _SetSessionRatingResponseData_ also has a  parameter for passing json data into the method as some _JObject_ representation, but the method is not using it at all. (I also have secondary concerns about why _SetSessionRatingResponseData_ has a parameter specifically of type _JObject_, but i don't want to write an  essay about all my concerns and musing here in the comments, so i'll put these aside...)

Comment: `new ResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(LoadJson());` does not make any sense in C# syntax, it should be something like `var ResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(LoadJson());`. On top of what the previous comments pointed out.

Comment: Hi, OP here. I am writing this method from scratch, so It may have a few errors. I have a Jobject in the method because my Idea later on is to call this method by passing in the above LoadJson() return. That can be ignored for sorry, apologies I should have removed that when posting here (as that is a future attempt once got this working locally). 

I have tried this and it seems to be correct in syntax:
var ResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UnderwrittenResponseModel>(LoadJson());

Should I be able to use the variable ResponseModel from then on assuming it deserialises?

Comment: Hi, OP again to finish comment. unfortunately I cannot post the json as it contains work data, also it's huge so emptying it out and replacing everything would just be a bit pointless. I'm just going to assume the json and models are correct and I can investigate further once I create the model.

It was more so that I had a model I could create. I presume: 

var ResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UnderwrittenResponseModel>(LoadJson());

Should suffice? Thanks for that help by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a constructor defined on your ResponseModel,the new keyword is trying to initialize a new struct.

Try replacing the new call to create an instance of ResponseModel without the constructor and use the json Deserilize instead-- e.g.

ResponseModel responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(LoadJson());

and set session constants accordingly

Comment: Lovely thanks for the help! and the information also, I shall lookup constructors further for more information.